# Belongs_to and Has_one in same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models: Photographer and Picture. A photographer has several pictures and a picture belongs to a photographer. Thus, the model Photographer I implemented the policy has_many:pictures and on the model Picture belongs_to :photographer.

All right here. However, a photographer can choose an picture for the cover of your profile. So, I added the field cover_id to the table and pointed the model Photographer belongs_to :cover, class_name: "Image". My problem is how to display this relationship at the other end, the model Picture, which already has a relationship with belongs_to :photographer.

Thought I'd add a picture field indicating that this would be the case, however, this solution would allow more than a cover for the same photographer.

Complementing the question, I should obligatorily specify both ends of a relationship in Rails?

Tks

Comment: can an image be deleted?  also is a cover_id required?

Comment: This question appears more suited to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes, image can be deleted. And no, cover is not required. Sorry Chris, I didn't know this Code Review...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would first argue that a (profile) picture does not own a photographer. Instead, a photographer should have one profile picture. And this same type of object can also play the role of pictures that the photographer owns but used for purposes other than a profile photo. I think STI make s sense.

```
class Photographer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures
  has_one :profile_picture
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :photographer
end

class ProfilePicture < Picture
  belongs_to :photographer
end
```

This way you can assign the one profile picture for the photographer as well as create many pictures using the same database table for both like-models.

```
photographer = Photographer.create!
profile_picture = ProfilePicture.create!

photographer.profile_picture = profile_picture
photographer.save!

photographer.pictures.create!    
photographer.pictures.create!
photographer.pictures.count #=> 3
```

Comment: what would happen if I asked ProfilePicture.all?

Comment: It will execute the sql query `SELECT "pictures".* FROM "pictures" WHERE "pictures"."type" IN ('ProfilePicture')`. So all records where type is `ProfilePicture`.

Comment: Where did this "type"? Should I implement a field in the table? I never implement a inheritance persisted in the database.

Comment: The type field should be added to the `pictures` table in your database. By convention, rails will understand how to instantiate objects of multiple classes that are all mapped to the same table. This is useful if each class will have the same set of attributes, but differ in behavior. Scroll down to "Single table inheritance" here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html for the official documentation. And the explanation from [Martin Fowler](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html).