# Ruby on Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, carrierwave

I have a User model (using devise gem) and I want a User to be able to upload a profile picture as they create an account. The file handling is handled using carrierwave.

The issue I am having is that the image row does not get created. I'm not getting any errors about invalid parameters, the image row just simply isn't being created.

Here is my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessor :profile_image, :profile_image_attributes
  has_many :images
  has_one :profile_image
  has_many :contents
  has_many :comments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile_image
end
```

And the sign_up_params method inside of my RegistrationsController

```
def sign_up_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:forename, :surname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, profile_image_attributes: [:content, :file])
end
```

Here is the fields_for

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.fields_for :profile_image, resource.build_profile_image do |image_form| %>
      <%= image_form.label :file, 'Profile Picture' %> <br>
      <%= image_form.file_field :file %> <br>
      <%= image_form.label :content, 'Description' %> <br>
      <%= image_form.text_area :content %> <br>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And here is the log of the user row being created. Nothing about creating an image row is displayed.

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2016-11-06 17:04:57 +0000
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"vxAHJwH79yRdD/SbayZRNQ3oLFZlz9AGqyGS93OhPCJsUxN9RuQqQtuvwcOK8NQBho7fSI4hJtErssZFfm+sxw==", "user"=>{"email"=>"adf@a", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "forename"=>"a", "surname"=>"a", "profile_image_attributes"=>{"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x78853f8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/James/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20161106-17292-1r0dgj.jpg>, @original_filename="irishgarud.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[profile_image_attributes][file]\"; filename=\"irishgarud.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "content"=>""}}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mUser Exists (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'adf@a' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mSQL (1.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "users" ("forename", "surname", "email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["forename", "a"], ["surname", "a"], ["email", "adf@a"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$EdO.kR.MKHpb2nLQ/tW5U.IsMPWjrMxil1o5eVtekYFCefn9EL/xO"], ["created_at", "2016-11-06 17:04:57.193320"], ["updated_at", "2016-11-06 17:04:57.193320"]]
  [1m[35m (85.2ms)[0m  commit transaction
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (1.0ms)[0m  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = ?, "current_sign_in_at" = ?, "last_sign_in_ip" = ?, "current_sign_in_ip" = ?, "sign_in_count" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["last_sign_in_at", "2016-11-06 17:04:57.281545"], ["current_sign_in_at", "2016-11-06 17:04:57.281545"], ["last_sign_in_ip", "::1"], ["current_sign_in_ip", "::1"], ["sign_in_count", 1], ["updated_at", "2016-11-06 17:04:57.281545"], ["id", 30]]
  [1m[36m (78.0ms)[0m  [1mcommit transaction[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 485ms (ActiveRecord: 166.2ms)
```

profile_image is just a subclass of my image model. I'm essentially doing the same thing as can be seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16658099/5660258).

Comment: Why does `User` have `profile_image` as both an association name and an accessor?

Comment: No clue as to why I put it there. I removed the accessor and it works as intended now. Thanks for pointing that out.